# How to post or get data form aws dynamodb through endponint api using x-api-key, accesskey and securityKey in python

Tags: python, rest, api, amazon-dynamodb

I'm new to using API endpoints in python. How can I access dynamodb table in aws using self created API endpoint (url)?

I have access key and security key of aws, and the x-api-key of the endpoint url.

I'm able to post the details to dynamodb with postman tool using above given details, but I want to run this in a Python script. Please answer with a sample example, if possible. Thank you.

Comment: If you're using python, my advice is to boto3 the AWS SDK, if for some reason you cannot or are a masochist reference the python urllib (https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html) and the AWS Dynamo REST API docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.LowLevelAPI.html)

Comment: I can access the dynamoDB table with boto3, using the existing modules from it, but now i to access the table using an api endpoint, and that api gateway is user created. so i am not sure how to access it with the keys given, that i have mentioned in the above query. Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access dynamodb VIA the rest endpoints you'll need to sign your requests with your credentials.

You're in luck because they have examples how to sign your requests with python

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html

Comment: Thank you, will give it a try, this is my first time working on this stuff.